# Using the contraction mapping principle for the solution of an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, contraction-operator

Suppose we want to solve a simple ODE $$\dot{x}=2t(1-x)=f(t,x)\qquad (1)$$ with initial condition $x_0=2$ using the contraction mapping principle.

I showed that $f$ is uniformly Lipschitz continuous in $x$ over $[0,1]\times\mathbb R$ for all $t\in[0,1]$ with Lipschitz constant $L=2$.

Considering a normed vector space $(C[0,\delta],||\cdot||_C)$, the contraction map with $P:C[0,\delta]\to C[0,\delta]$ given by $$(P\phi)(t)=x_0+\int_{0}^{t}f(t,\phi(\tau))\;d\tau.$$

Now, by direct integration the solution of $(1)$ is $$x=1+\exp(-t^2).$$

So far we have shown that there exists a unique solution over the interval $[0,\delta]$, right?

Is the next step to provide an argument using the contraction mapping that shows that the solution is unique over the entire set of positive real numbers?

I am not sure how to make this argument. I thought that maybe by iteration and increasing $\delta$ one can show that the solution is unique over a bigger interval. But this doesn't see formal/rigorous.

I'd appreciate any help/hint. Thank you.

Comment: Hint: for large $T$, $P: C[-T,T] \rightarrow C[-T,T]$ defined by, 

$$(P\phi)(t) = x_0 + \int_0^t f(\tau,\phi(\tau))\,d\tau,$$

is no longer a contraction mapping. However, for any such fixed $T$, there exists a $k$ such that $P^k$ is a contraction mapping. Try proving this and you will have your result.

Comment: There is a result stating that if $f\colon(a,b)\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous and there are continuous functions $M_1,M_2\colon(a,b)\to[0,\infty)$ such that $\lvert f(t,x)\rvert\le M_1(t)+M_2(t)\lvert x\rvert$ for all $t\in(a,b)$ and all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ then any nonextendible solution of $\dot{x}=f(t,x)$ is defined on the whole of $(a,b)$. The proof uses [Grönwall's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality).

Comment: @user539887 can you please provide a reference of the result you're talking about?

Comment: @forgottenarrow when you write $\mathcal{P}^k$, does $k$ represent a power?

Comment: For example, theorem 2.17 on p. 53 of the online version of G. Teschl's book [Ordinary Differential Equations and Dynamical Systems](https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~gerald/ftp/book-ode/) gives a proof for the case $(a,b)=(-\infty,\infty)$. A proof in the general case is analogous (the crux is that if a nonextendible solution is defined on a smaller interval then it must leave any compact set, which is impossible by the inequality obtained).

Comment: @johnny09 Yes, it's a power. More precisely, it represents repeated composition. So $P^2\phi = P(P\phi)$, and so on. The point I was making is that even if $P$ is not a contraction, if you iterate it enough times (for any fixed, finite $T$), you will eventually end up with a contraction.